# Does the noise figure of a cable change if the load/source is mismatched?

Tags: noise, transmission-line

I know that the noise figure of a transmission line is equal to its attenuation (usually expressed as dB/m or dB/100 ft).  However, what if there is a mismatch between the line's characteristic impedance and the source and/or load?  Do the losses in the lines increase as a result?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that if there are reflections then the reflected wave energy is subject to a second, third and fourth (etc.) pass down the cable so the losses in the line increase.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: mismatches in impedance cause reflected standing waves, which reduce the efficiency of energy transmission, much like increased attenuation in the cables.

Answer (score -1):

Noise figure increases when there is an INPUT impedance mismatch.  When there is an input impedance mismatch, you start with a lower Signal level, but the stage adds the same amount of noise, so the SNR at the output is worse. And the Signal level at the output is lower, so you have to amplify more later, so finally not only is the SNR worse, but the absolute Noise Level is worse at the final output too.

Which is also just another way of saying that Noise Figure in the first stage is much more important than NF in later stages.

So, the MOST IMPORTANT fact about cable output impedance mis-match, is that it destroys the Noise Figure of the System much more badly than the small effect of increasing the thermal noise of the cable itself due to increased power dissapation.

Comment: A cable doesn't isolate output from input like an amplifier does. Nor does it provide gain that will reduce the input SNR of any amplifiers it feeds. So why do you say a mismatch at the input is more important than mismatch at the output when we're talking about a cable?

Comment: @The Photon "Mismatch at the input to the device" is important. The important effect of cable mismatch is on the "Mismatch at the input to the device", not on the "losses in the line"/"efficiency in energy transfer" mentioned in the question and in the other response.

Comment: Ok, that's more clear. I thought you were talking about mismatch at the input to the cable. If you edit the clarification into your answer, I'll remove my -1.